# MVC 3 application hosted in web browser control on CE 6 not displaying images correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, compact-framework

I have an MVC 3 application that we run on our handhelds inside a web browser control. The devices run either CE5 or CE6.

When an image is requested on CE5, the image is displayed fine, but on CE 6 the image appears to download but doesn't actually appear until the page is clicked.

Once this happens, the image is cached (somehow) and is fine going forward for that session.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

This is the only other page I can find that mentions the issue but no solution is mentioned:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/0396d869-2ac2-4d38-8565-2d308eb8573a/

**EDIT:**

The view code is below. Model.DisplayItem would return a string like:

~/Areas/R2D2Picking/Content/images/M00119.jpg

The actual images are on a separate drive (rather than part of the solution) so we access these by creating the folder structure in the solution, excluding this from the build and creating a virtual directory under the relevant root in IIS. We use this method in many of our applications so I don't believe that this would itself be an issue.

```
@using R2D2Picking.Models.ViewModels;
@using System.IO;
@using System.Net;

@model ItemImageVM        

<div class='backImage'>

    <a href="@Url.Action("PickSelectedItems", "Common")" onfocus="if(this.blur)this.blur()">
    <img alt='' src="@Url.Content("~/Areas/R2D2Picking/Content/ButtonImages/BackButton.bmp")" /></a>

</div>

<div class='smallPrompt'>
    <p>@Model.DisplayLiteral</p>
</div>

@if (Model.ImageExists())
{
    <div class='itemImage'>
        <a href="@Url.Action("PickSelectedItems", "Common")">
        <img alt='' src="@Url.Content(@Model.DisplayItem)" /></a>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class='noImage'>
        <a href="@Url.Action("PickSelectedItems", "Common")">
        <img alt='' src="@Url.Content("~/Areas/R2D2Picking/Content/ButtonImages/no_picture.bmp")" /></a>
    </div>
}
```

A sample image is below:

[image]

Comment: What code are you using to display the image? What kind of image (gif, jpeg)? If it doesn't violate anything with your company, can you edit and upload the image?

Comment: As a postscript to this - we ended up adding some javascript to click outside the visible window to get round the problem.